# How to create a local checkboxes by jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

example is : [alt text http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/chris_mao/EntryImages/20090323/Sel.JPG](http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/chris_mao/EntryImages/20090323/Sel.JPG)

But example is php,I dont't understand  php how to use. Who can tell me html+jquery how to write?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  `$('<input type=checkbox>')` is enough to create a checkbox with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and write it yourself. But there are some jQuery plugins available to make this fairly easy. Try this one for example: http://floatmargin.com/demos/checkboxtree/checkboxtree.html

Download here: http://github.com/magearwhig/jquery-checkboxtree